# Add iFrame to each node on a D3 collapsible tree plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, d3.js

as per the subject, im trying to add a small iFrame to each node on a d3 tree.
My goal is, when a user clicks on a certain node text within the tree, the iframe attached to that node will load up a the page associated with that node.
To date ive managed to get a single iframe on screen(using the code below(index.aspx)) but not on each node, ive also got the clickable node text part going ok along with returning the URL for the iframe source.
Hope ive explained my issue clearly enough.

Thanks.

```
function update(source) {

        // Compute the new tree layout.
        var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
            links = tree.links(nodes);

        // Normalize for fixed-depth.
        nodes.forEach(function (d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

        // Update the nodes…
        var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

        // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
        ;

        nodeEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 1e-6)
            .style("fill", function (d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
            .on("click", click)
        ;

        nodeEnter.append("text")
            .attr("x", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("text-anchor", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
            .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

        nodeEnter
            .append("a")
            .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return d.SiteUrl; })
            .append("rect")

            .attr("class", "clickable")
            .attr("y", -6)
            .attr("x", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? -60 : 10; })
            .attr("width", 50) //2*4.5)
            .attr("height", 12)
            .style("fill", "lightsteelblue")
            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6) // set to .3 to make visible

            //On mouse hover, page description
            .append("title").text(function (d) { return d.Description; })
        ;

        //iFrame per node
        nodeEnter.append("iframe")
            .attr("src", function(d) {
                return d.SiteUrl;  //src for each frame
            })
            .attr("width", 50)
            .attr("height", 50);


        // Transition nodes to their new position.
        var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

        nodeUpdate.select("circle")
            .attr("r", 4.5)
            .style("fill", function (d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

        nodeUpdate.select("text")
            .style("fill-opacity", 1);

        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
        var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
            .remove();

        nodeExit.select("circle")
            .attr("r", 1e-6);

        nodeExit.select("text")
            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

        // Update the links…
        var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
            .data(links, function (d) { return d.target.id; });

        // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
        link.enter().insert("path", "g")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
                return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
            });

        // Transition links to their new position.
        link.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("d", diagonal);

        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
        link.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                var o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
                return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
            })
            .remove();

        // Stash the old positions for transition.
        nodes.forEach(function (d) {
            d.x0 = d.x;
            d.y0 = d.y;
        });
    }

    // Toggle children on click.
    function click(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
        } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iframe` are not allowed within `svg` elements. To include them, you would need a [`foreignObject` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/extend.html#ForeignObjectElement).

```js
    //iFrame per node
    nodeEnter
        .append('foreignObject')
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height", 50);       
        .append("iframe")
        .attr("src", function(d) {
            return d.SiteUrl;  //src for each frame
        })
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height", 50);
```

I am not sure why this code will work for one `iFrame`, as you suggest it does.

**Update:**

To add a `foreignObject` to the `svg` on `click`, do this in the `click` function:

```js
function click(d) {
    d3.select('svg')  // This should be the parent element which set viewport
        .append('foreignObject')
        .attr('class', function (d) { return 'object-' + d.id; })
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height", 50);       
        .append("iframe")
        .attr("src", function(d) {
            return d.SiteUrl;  //src for each frame
        })
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height", 50);
}
```

The `d` object passed to the `click` handler is the `data` element associated with the object which was clicked. Hence, you can find `d.x` and `d.y` using it. Also, add a class to the `element` so that it can be searched for later and removed.

Comment: Still no iFrames on screen still. They do however appear in the browser debug console.  Could this be because it is loading after the DOM ?

Comment: Yes. nothing on the rendered page, but the debug console shows - <foreignObject x="443.33333333333337" y="180" width="50" height="50"><iframe width="50" height="50" src="http://myServer/geometricmodelling/en/14785.aspx"></iframe></foreignObject>

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge but it seems the browser is trying to load/render the iFrame before the nodes..

Comment: Indeed, the browser will try to load them when they are inserted in the DOM. I guess they should be added to the DOM only when the user clicks on the node, in the `click` function. However, I don't think the `circle` tag can accept tags inside it. One would should add the `iFrames` on it's container (or `svg` element) and position it accordingly.

Comment: How would i add the iframes to the svg container and position /

Comment: This issue is the same for creating div's, SVG just cant seem to render iframes or divs with text inside them.

Comment: If using `foreignObject` tag doesn't work, then you can try adding them to `body`, set `position: relative` on body and then position them absolutely at their respective place over the nodes.

Comment: In the end resorted to moving the iframe(that was on the body), to the mouse location, once clicked.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But that means the `iFrames` are being loaded beforehand?

Comment: Yes, the blank iframe is being loaded before hand away from where the svg is going to be loaded to, then the SVG is loaded with populated nodes.  When a node is clicked the iframe re-positions to the mouse click location over the top of the svg.   This is not ideal really, as the iframe covers the links and other nodes.